# RichTextBox защищенный текст

Tags: c#, wpf

В *WinForm RTB* есть возможность защитить текст от изменения при помощи атрибута `SelectionProtected`.

Есть ли такая возможность в *RTB*, который используется в *WPF*?

Единственное, что нашлось похожее, это свойство *IsSealed* во *FlowDocument* и *Block*.  Нужно блокировать не весь текст а только его часть

Comment: А нельзя просто положить внутрь `Label` или `TextBlock` с нужным текстом?

Comment: Document грузится из rtf документа, будет ли возможность подменить block?

Comment: Ну, вручную. Найти нужный текст и подменить по идее можно.

Comment: Такой способ помог но на половину(, вставляю TextBlock, в RTB его отредактировать нельзя но можно удалить(

Comment: Хм. А что должно произойти, если пользователь выделяет всё и нажимает Del?

Comment: Не чего... Если в выделенный текс попадает защищенный текст то он его не должен дать удалить

Answer (score 2):

За это отвечает атрибут `IsReadOnly`:

```
<RichTextBox IsReadOnly="True">
```

Comment: Данный атрибут блокирует контрол а не выделенный текст, а мне нужен именно выделенный текст или часть текста